# How to use WooCommerce product base price with jQuery | Gravity Form

Tags: jquery, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

Why doesn't the below work, and how should I do this?
Do you have a better and shorter way to write this code?

I also viewed this page but did not notice:
[enter link description here](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_product_total/)

```
$(function() {

var FinalPrice;
var BasePrice = $('.woocommerce-variation-price .amount').text();
// I think the problem is here


$('.Select_plooi input[type="radio"]').on('change',function(){  
var plooi=$('input[name="input_4"]:checked').val();

switch (plooi)
{
    case 'Enkele':
        FinalPrice=BasePrice*2;
        break;
    case 'Dubble':
        FinalPrice=BasePrice*5;
        break;
    case 'Wave':
        FinalPrice=BasePrice*6;
        break;
        }
    });
    
$("#input_2_9").val(parseFloat(FinalPrice).toFixed(2));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$('.woocommerce-variation-price .amount') will return price with currency symbol html element is not Int
try this:

```
var BasePrice = parseFloat($('.woocommerce-variation-price .amount').text().replace(/[^\d.,]/g, '')); // remove all non numeric
```